# How to turn back on prompt for conflict resolution during deployment vs/wss 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I managed to turn off prompt for conflict resolution during deployment.

How can I turn this back on?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the Artifact node in VS.NET (for example, List Instance node etc). Right-click on that node and select Properties. You should see a propety named "Deployment Conflict Resolution", that will give you option to change it.